# PHP $_SERVER[‘SERVER_ADDR’] variable always returns 127.0.0.1

Tags: php, linux, lamp, superglobals, server-farm

We have multiple load-balanced webserver machines running the same PHP webapp ([LAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_(software_bundle))) and I'd like to run slightly different code on each server (*for testing purposes*). I was hoping to use the `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` super global to do something like this:

```
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] == 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX') {
  echo "Do one thing";
} elseif ($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] == 'YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY') {
  echo "Do something else";
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work because both machines are setting `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` to '**127.0.0.1**'. How can I configure them so that `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` is set to their public IP address?

I'm guessing the issue may be something to do with `/etc/hosts` so for refererence it currently looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain localhost
::1             localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
XXX.XX.XX.XX    blahblah
```

### Update...

**Oops**! I neglected to consider the [nginx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx) reverse proxy in front of the web servers. All the traffic to those web servers arrives from nginx due to the following line in the nginx conf:

```
location / {
    root                  /var/www/staging/current;
    proxy_pass            http://localhost:8880;
}
```

Comment: is that when you access via http://localhost or via http://blahbl.ah ?

Comment: This is happening when I access the site publicly, i.e from the IP of the load-balancer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Surely it's as simple as

```
$ip = getHostByName(php_uname('n')); 
echo $ip;
```

Comment: I didn't know these PHP functions - Thanks for letting me know about them.

Comment: just another as bad solution vulnerable to the same errors... for example on my system this exactly code putouts 127.0.1.1

Answer (score 4):

It would probably involve changing how the load-balancer connects to the server. I don't know what software this is.

You might be better off switching based on some other factor that changes between the machines. A good bet would be the hostname:

```
$host= php_uname('n');
switch($host) {
    case 'webserver1':
        ...do one thing...
        break;
    case 'webserver2':
        ...do another thing...
        break;
    default:
        die('No configuration for unknown host '.$host);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

reverse rows in /etc/hosts

```
XXX.XX.XX.XX    blahblah
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain localhost
::1             localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
```

should work

Comment: I have the `127.0.0.1` entry first and it works fine... Perhaps this has to do with the Apache configuration?

Comment: I tried reversing these rows (remembering to restart the networking service and Apache) - but unfortunately had no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Use this more accurate!

```
echo getHostByName($_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]);
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix my issue, I have 3 ideas:

1. I might hardcode the IP address of each server into a PHP variable in a config file that we have on each server.
2. I might use the *reverse proxy add forward module for Apache* ([mod_rpaf](http://stderr.net/apache/rpaf/)).
3. I might change the `proxy_pass` on each server to go to `XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8880` and `YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY:8880` rather than `localhost`?

Answer (score 0):

you should really have som server specific config that gets loaded and a server id inside.
every system will behave differently and going for ip adresses, hostname is definately very error vulnerable. usually there are many applications on the server and from one day to another it might not work any longer and you will have a hard time debugging (for example some1 geths the nice idea to set up a reverse entry so mails dont get spammed any more?)

Answer (score 0):

In Apache 2.4 and later  $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] if you are calling the server from the localhost it will return something like ::1 instead of 127.0.0.1

To solve that go to your Apache conf file and change

```
Listen 80
```

to

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
```

Finally make sure that your server is not behind a reverse proxy