# How to avoid the user pass a localhost or 127.0.0.1 or self ip to loadHTML?

Tags: php, security

I have a simple function for checking the web site title:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTMLFile($aUrl);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);     

if(!isset($xpath->query('//title')->item(0)->nodeValue)) 
{             
     return FALSE;
}                              

return $xpath->query('//title')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

But if the user pass the localhost or 127.0.0.1, they can get my host data, I can make a simple guide to allow user input these value, but sometimes, I can't ensure the internal ip, like 192.168.11.2, how can I protect the site won't query back my host? Thank you.

Comment: You are permitting users to supply any URL value for `$aUrl`? That's exceedingly dangerous

Comment: @Michael Not at all. That's what proxies do all the time.

Comment: @phihag Proxies typically have a whitelist of acceptable domains to proxy

Comment: Why so dangerous? any results? And, how to avoid them... moreover, what can I do to enhance the security from my functions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this line to begining

```
if( preg_match( "/^(http:\/\/)(localhost|127.0.0.1|{$_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"]}|{$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]}|www.yourhost.net)/i", $aUrl )) die( 'error' );
```

it may help

Comment: but they still get access me via 192.168.11.2 :(

Comment: $_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"] contains 192.168.11.2 ( or your actual server address ), see http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: I get the result is 127.0.0.1 instead of 192.168.11.2. But I can get access from 192.168.11.2 :(

Comment: see this for getting correct IP - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202872/php-serverserver-addr-variable-always-returns-127-0-0-1    but i think, correct apache setup will fix it - this dependes on what you have in bind address

Answer (score -1):

127.0.0.1 or localhost for the external user will be their own computer / host
set a condition, where you check the hostname is not $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] or $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']

Comment: Nope, he's sending requests from the server with curl.